# nginx ldap auth bypass for specifc networks

Tags: authentication, networking, nginx, ldap, debian

I am running nginx v1.6.3 on debian jessie 8.5 with this module compiled: https://github.com/kvspb/nginx-auth-ldap

When connecting to a site from different subnets I want the following behaviour:
    Subnet A: needs auth via ldap
    Subnet B: no auth

I tried the geo modul to turn on ldap_auth only if subnet A matches, but it still needs auth.

Parts of my config
    geo $val {
        default 0;
        10.0.0.0/24 1;
    }

```
server {
...
location / {
    if ($val) {
        ldap_auth ....
    }
}
```

error.log:
    2016/06/23 23:48:50 [emerg] 3307#0: "auth_ldap" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/proxy:32

I thought about adding an switch auth_ldap_bypass to the ldap_auth nginx module, but I'm not into programming modules for nginx. Maybe there is a solution out there.

Comment: I found a temporary workaround: Copy the nginx site config. Let it listen on a different port. Use iptables to redirect traffic from specific subnets to the nginx site with or without auth.